# Prove that 1-form is exact using the fundamental Group Homomorphism

Tags: complex-analysis, fundamental-groups

I have the following group homomorphism: $\pi_1(i,z_o):\pi_1(U,z_o)\rightarrow \pi_1(\mathbb{C},z_o)$ where $i$ is the inclusion map and I know that it is the null-homomorphism, i.e.
 $\pi_1(i,z_o)([\alpha]) = [C_{z_o}] $ for every $[\alpha]$ in $\pi_1(U,z_o)$.

I have to prove that the 1-form $\omega=\frac{dz}{z}$ is exact on $U$.

I think that the idea of the proof uses the fact that if $U$ is simply connected then $\omega$ is exact; however, I don't know how to see that $U$ is simply connected when only knowing  that the inclusion is  the null-homomorphism.

Comment: $\pi_1(\mathbb{C},z_0)=\{e\}$, since $\mathbb{C}$ is simply connected. Thus $\{e\}=\pi_1(\mathbb{C},z_0)\simeq \pi(U,z_0)/(\text{Ker}(\pi_1(i,z_0)))$ by the first isomorphism theorem. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I would appreciate if you can explain it a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have said as the inclusion is the null-homomorphism, every loop in U is null-homologous in $\mathbb{C}$.

Now as $U$ is connected $w$ is exact on $U \iff w $ is local exact and for every loop $\alpha :\int_{\alpha}w=0$

$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is homorphic in $\mathbb{C}^*$ by Goursat's theorem $w = \frac{dz}{z}$ is local exact on $\mathbb{C}^*$

$w$ local exact on $\mathbb{C} \Rightarrow$ $w$ local exact on $U$

Finally as for every $\alpha$ in U, $\alpha$ is null-homologous $\int_{\alpha}w=0$ and $w$ is exact.